# How do I modify the stack list of sys.exc_info()?

Tags: python, list, exception, stack

I'd like to remove a couple of frames from the stack list that represent a decorator before logging it, but when I try to get to it, the debugger says that there is no such attribute as `stack` even though PyCharm shows it:

```py
sys.exc_info()[2].tb_frame.stack  # <-- AttributeError, but why?
```

[image]

This is what I would like to do:

```py
sys.exc_info()[2].tb_frame.stack = sys.exc_info()[2].tb_frame.stack[3:]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FWIW, I can't see an attribute for `stack` on a `traceback.tb_frame` object in python 3.8:

```py
try:
    raise Exception('test')
except:
    cls, e, tb = sys.exc_info()

hasattr(tb.tb_frame, 'stack')
False
```

You can probably do this in a `for` loop by tracing the `tb_next` attribute on the traceback:

```py
try:
    do_something()
except Exception as e:
    cls, exc, tb = sys.exc_info()

    for _ in range(3):
        tb_next = tb.tb_next

        # in case you don't have that many frames
        if not tb_next:
            break

        tb = tb_next

    raise cls.with_traceback(tb)
```

Comment: @t3chb0t exactly. Since it's much easier to modify the traceback and step through as many frames as you need to, then raise the exception with a slightly shortened traceback

Comment: It works! I didn't raise a new exception, but I used the loop to modify the traceback and then to recreate the `tuple` that is used by logging's `record.exc_info` so now the formatter seeing fewer frames doesn't show my telemetry logging decorator that handles the exception anymore.